# how to remove /n and comma while extracting using response.css

Tags: python, css, web-scraping

I am trying to crawl amazon to get product name, price and [savings information]. i am using response.css to extract [saving information] as below

python code to extract [savings information]:

```
savingsinfo = amzscrape.css(".a-color-secondary .a-row , .a-row.a-size-small.a-color-secondary span").css('::text').extract()
```

Returning below output with above code

```
'savingsinfo_item': ['Save ',                                                   
                     '$20.00',
                     ' when you buy ',
                     '$100.00',
                     ' of select items']
```

Expected output:

```
Save $20.00 when you buy $100 of select items
```

Comment: All you have to do is `' '.join(savingsinfo['savingsinfo_item']`

Comment: `joined_str = " ".join(savingsinfo['savingsinfo_item'])`

Comment: i didnt understand where should i add this. Savingsinfo_item is a output container.

Comment: @user11894930 As I understood, `savingsinfo` is a dictionary with one key which is `savingsinfo_item`... Am I right?

Comment: you printed out your result right then you can access your variable so the output looks like dict so we can get dict value by `savingsinfo['savingsinfo_item']` it contains list so using `"".join.(list)` can join your list to one string just like what you wanted did i understand wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```py
output = ''.join(savingsinfo['savingsinfo_item'])
```

Comment: This will concatenate all words together with no separation.. I think you meant to add a space to the `join`.

Comment: @Anwarvic the list already has the spaces embedded in it: `'Save '`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This returns a list. All you need is to join the items as shown.

```
list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
seperator = ' '
print(seperator.join(list))
```